# no default constructor exists for class Move

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I developed two modules with separate implementation and interfaces.
These are the ones:

This is file `Move.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include "utils.h"

class Move {
private:
    int x;
    int y;

public:
    Move(int x_inp, int y_inp);
    char getX();
    int getY();
};
```

And this is `Move.cpp`:

```
#include "Move.h"

Move::Move(int x_inp, int y_inp) {
    int size = 10
    this->x = x_inp;
    this->y = y_inp;
};

int Move::getX() {
    return this->x;
};

int Move::getY() {
    return this->y;
}
```

This is the file `Node.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include "Move.h"
#include <vector>


class Node {
private:
    Move move;
    Node* parent;
    std::vector <Node*> children;

public:
    Node(Move inp_move, Node* parent_inp);

    double value(const float EXPLORE_CONST);
    void add_children(std::vector<Node*>);
};

#include "Node.cpp"

Node::Node(Move inp_move, Node* parent_inp) {  // this is where compilation error rises.
    this->move = inp_move;
    this->parent = parent_inp;
}

void Node::add_children(std::vector<Node*> list_of_children) {
    for (Node* item : list_of_children) {
        this->children.push_back(item);
    }
}
```

It always gives me the error that no default constructor exists for class "Move". I am really stuck and try to figure out the solution but didn't find the answer.

Can you guys help me please.
Thanks

Comment: Well, it's true - no default constructor exists. Try adding 'Move() = default;' in the public section of your move class and one will exist.

Comment: Your constructor, `Node::Node()`, since you haven't supplied an initialiser list, is equivalent to `Node::Node(Move inp_move, Node* parent_inp) : move(), parent() {this->move = ino_move; this->parent = parent_inp;}`.   Notice the default construction of `move` (and `parent`) before assigning in the constructor body.  Either change that constructor to use an initialiser list, viz `Node::Node(Move inp_move, Node* parent_inp) : move(inp_move), parent(inp_parent) {}` or give `Move` a default constructor.

Comment: Don't provide default constructor if your class doesn't need one. Use member initializer list like Marek's answer suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try literally adding a default constructor to your "Move" class.

```
public:
    Move() {}    
//default constructor

    Move(int x_inp, int y_inp);
    char getX();
    int getY();
};
´´´´
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor):

```cpp
Node::Node(Move inp_move, Node* parent_inp) 
   : move{inp_move}
   , parent{parent_inp}
{
}
```

Or provide default constructor for `Move` as suggested in comment. IMO use of member initializer lists is better choice.